# Get data result from second Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my MainActivity extends FragmentActivity, I have a FragmentA, When I press a Button in FragmentA, I call to FragmentB.

```
FragmentB f = FragmentB.newInstance(1);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.llMain, f).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

In FragmentB, I create a Object People p1(with Name and age) . And When I press a Button B in FragmentB, I call

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

It will return FragmentA,

So, I want to pass data Object People p1 from FragmentB to FragmentA. What do i have to do?
I try to search but can't find a solution.

Comment: You should use a global/static Singleton class like Application. And make it manage the data you want several of the fragments/activity to access. Then you can get it every where you need

Comment: You can refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: For that you have make a Custom common class use a static variable

Comment: simple as that since the two fragment use same activity then it can be like this. FragmentB -> Activity -> FragmentA

Answer (score 0):

create CallBack in your Fragment and handle it in FragmentActivity, 
[google example has this realization](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

> declaring OnHeadlineSelectedListener callback

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

// The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can deliver messages
public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    /** Called by HeadlinesFragment when a list item is selected */
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // We need to use a different list item layout for devices older than Honeycomb
    int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

    // Create an array adapter for the list view, using the Ipsum headlines array
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, Ipsum.Headlines));
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Notify the parent activity of selected item
    mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);

    // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

> Realize callback method in FragmentActivity and send (by .setArguments()) data from HeadLinesFragment to ArticleFragment, if ArticleFragment is available

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
    implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

    // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
        HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
        // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }
}

public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment

    // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
    ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

    if (articleFrag != null) {
        // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

        // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
        articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);

    } else {
        // If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

        // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
        ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction =             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use an interface within Activity for communication between fragments. Check this [android training lesson](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

> All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

You can pass arguments to a Fragment with `Bundle`. Change your code to:

```
FragmentB f = FragmentB.newInstance(1);

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("NAME", name);
args.putInt("AGE", age);
f.setArguments(args);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.llMain, f).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

and then retrieve the arguments for example in FragmentA's onCreateView with:

```
int age = getArguments().getInt("AGE");
//or with a second parameter as the default value
int age = getArguments().getInt("AGE", 0);
```

If you want to pass the whole People object to the Bundle, you need to make the class serializable. I think it's easier to pass the variables and then recreate the object.