# Android pass argument from fragment to previous fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Need your help to figure out what is the best approach to achieve the following:

Activity -> Fragment A -> Fragment B.

When a user is on fragment B, and he clicks save. I want it to Remove/popBackStack Fragment B and return to Fragment A with the data passed from Fragment B.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354249/get-data-result-from-second-fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could define interface and  attribute in Fragment B,such as:

```
public interface OnSelectedListener {
    void onSelected(String s);
}

private OnSelectedListener mOnSelectedListener;

public void setOnSelectedListener(OnSelectedListener onSelectedListener) {
    mOnSelectedListener = onSelectedListener;
}
```

when Fragment A -> Fragment B:

```
new OnSelectedListener();
```

when click save in Fragment B

```
onSelectedListener.onSelected("");
```

other method : DataBase, SharedPreferencesHelper

Comment: Do i need to have the activity in the middle of the 2 fragments?

Comment: i feel that this is the best solution, but there is something missing here for me. How should i pass the listener from Frag A to B? how to use the setOnSelectedListener?

Comment: in FragmentA:
FragmentB.setOnSelectedListener(new OnSelectedListener() );

FragmentA.getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.content, FragmentB)    
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
LocalBroadcastManager
```

Web Reference with Example -

https://gist.github.com/Antarix/8131277

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution would be to save the desired values in `onPause` or `onStop` of your **fragment-B** using any preferred storage method (like SharedPreferences or SQLite) and load them back in the `onResume` or `onStart` of **fragment-A**.

or replace the save part by introducing a stub method in your Activity which takes the Bundle of values and pass-on to the other fragment.